# Given an expression using kets, such as '|2> + 4|3>+...,' find the largest ket index in a ket?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have some expressions containing Kets, like

```
|1> + Sqrt[6] |3>
```

where the kets are created using [esc]ket[esc]. How can I find the largest number inside a ket? For example I would expect:

```
LargestN[|1> + Sqrt[6] |3>] = 3
```

At the moment I am doing it through matching regular expressions in the FullForm:

```
LargestN[state_] := Max[ToExpression /@ (StringReplace[#, 
   RegularExpression@"\\D" -> ""] & /@ 
 StringCases[state // FullForm // ToString, 
  RegularExpression@"Operator\[ket, \\d+\]"])]
```

While this does work, does anyone know a nicer way to do this?

Edit: Just in case someone stumbles across this in the future and gets confused, my code above won't work for you as I had another package loaded that was causing kets to be represented as

```
Operator[ket, n]
```

rather than the conventional

```
Ket[n]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
expr= Ket[1] + Sqrt[6] Ket[3]

Max@Cases[expr, Ket[a_] -> a, Infinity]
```

> `3`

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I had another package loaded which was messing things up.

Comment: @RuviLecamwasam Of course, this should work also if you use the form `Operator[ket,n]` but you have to replace `Ket[a_]->a` with `Operator[ket,a_]->a`.